# Let $R$ be a ring with the property that whenever $a, b, c ∈ R$ with a $a\neq 0$ and $ab = ca$, it follows that $b = c$. Is $R$ a domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring with the property that whenever $a, b, c ∈ R$ with $a \neq 0$ and $ab = ca$, it follows that $b = c$. Prove that $R$ is commutative.

Does the cancellation statement imply it's also an integral domain?

Answer (score 1):

> Does the cancellation statement imply it's also an integral domain?

This solves itself, right? If $ab=0$ with $a\neq 0$, then $ab=0a$ implies $b=0$.

---

And also, for reference, an already existing version of the title question: [Show that a ring is commutative if it has the property that ab = ca implies b = c when $a\neq 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1214268/29335)

Comment: Thank you, I'm at work using my tablet. Having a harder time finding older questions.